TypeError: addChoices is not a function when using subcommands in Discord.JS API v14
I already have a discord bot that has a command with one option and multiple choices. I wanted to add subcommands where the user can first pick which command he wants, then he would pick a subcommand and then will have choices (each subcommand would have choices). I've tried to edit my code with the code from this guide:
https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/advanced-creation.html#subcommands
The relevant part of my code looked like this:
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('raids')
    .setDescription('Teams for Raids')
    .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
        subcommand
            .setName('incursion')
            .setDescription('Teams for Incursion Raids')
            .addUserOption(option => option.setName('incursion-team').setDescription('Name of the team')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
               {name: 'incursion mystic', value: 'incursion mystic'},
               {name: 'incursion tech', value: 'incursion tech'},
               {name: 'incursion mutant', value: 'incursion mutant'},
               {name: 'incursion bio', value: 'incursion bio'},
               {name: 'incursion skill', value: 'incursion skill'}
            ))),
        async execute(interaction) { .....}

Unofrtunately, I had a runtime error:
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618024+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618025+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: option.setName(...).setDescription(...).setRequired(...).addChoices is not a function
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618025+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/commands/raids.js:19:14
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618026+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1346:50)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618026+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MixedClass.addUserOption (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1320:17)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618026+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/commands/raids.js:17:5
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618027+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MixedClass.addSubcommand (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1449:50)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618027+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/commands/raids.js:13:3)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618028+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618028+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618030+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.618031+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
2024-05-07T19:58:53.626943+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice 
2024-05-07T19:58:53.627142+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.7.0
2024-05-07T19:58:53.627284+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.7.0>
2024-05-07T19:58:53.627473+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.7.0` to update!
2024-05-07T19:58:53.627525+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice 
2024-05-07T19:58:53.685516+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-05-07T19:58:53.706546+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2024-05-07T19:58:53.709578+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-05-07T19:59:00.435076+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2024-05-07T19:59:01.063403+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-05-07T19:59:01.657642+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2024-05-07T19:59:01.657719+00:00 app[worker.1]: > testing-bot@1.0.0 start
2024-05-07T19:59:01.657720+00:00 app[worker.1]: > node index.js
2024-05-07T19:59:01.657720+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231217+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/commands/raids.js:19
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231276+00:00 app[worker.1]:             .addChoices(
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231277+00:00 app[worker.1]:              ^
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231277+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231280+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: option.setName(...).setDescription(...).setRequired(...).addChoices is not a function
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231281+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/commands/raids.js:19:14
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231281+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MixedClass._sharedAddOptionMethod (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1346:50)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231281+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MixedClass.addUserOption (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1320:17)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231282+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at /app/commands/raids.js:17:5
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231282+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at MixedClass.addSubcommand (/app/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1449:50)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231283+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/commands/raids.js:13:3)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231284+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231284+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231284+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.231285+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
2024-05-07T19:59:02.237547+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice 
2024-05-07T19:59:02.237673+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.7.0
2024-05-07T19:59:02.237775+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.7.0>
2024-05-07T19:59:02.237893+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.7.0` to update!
2024-05-07T19:59:02.237931+00:00 app[worker.1]: npm notice 
2024-05-07T19:59:02.299621+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-05-07T19:59:02.321353+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed

Application doesn't recognize that addChoices is a function. What I did wrong?

You can't add choices directly on a subcommand, only on string, integer, and number options.

It's not possible to add choices to a subcommand. Also subcommands can't be set as required because it's already required to select one. What you could do is use a subcommand group:
new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName('raids')
.setDescription('Teams for Raids')
.addSubcommandGroup(group =>
    group
        .setName('incursion')
        .setDescription('Teams for Incursion Raids')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand => 
            subcommand
            .setName(`mystic`)
            .setDescription(`...`)
            .addUserOption(option => 
                option
                .setName('incursion-team')
                .setDescription('Name of the team')
            )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand => 
            subcommand
            .setName(`tech`)
            .setDescription(`...`)
            .addUserOption(option => 
                option
                .setName('incursion-team')
                .setDescription('Name of the team')
            )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand => 
            subcommand
            .setName(`mutant`)
            .setDescription(`...`)
            .addUserOption(option => 
                option
                .setName('incursion-team')
                .setDescription('Name of the team')
            )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand => 
            subcommand
            .setName(`bio`)
            .setDescription(`...`)
            .addUserOption(option => 
                option
                .setName('incursion-team')
                .setDescription('Name of the team')
            )
        )
        .addSubcommand(subcommand => 
            subcommand
            .setName(`skill`)
            .setDescription(`...`)
            .addUserOption(option => 
                option
                .setName('incursion-team')
                .setDescription('Name of the team')
            )
        )
)

The discord commands should look like this now:

/raids incursion mystic (user)
/raids incursion tech (user)
/raids incursion mutant (user)
/raids incursion bio (user)
/raids incursion skill (user)
You'd access the value of the subcommand group with interaction.options.getSubcommandGroup() and the subcommand of the group with interaction.options.getSubcommand().

Lemme know if I made any mistakes 'cause I didn't test it
